# Number To Words Java

Tags: java

I have a homework in my programming class that makes a program that can change numbers(`Integer`) to Words(`String`).
We can only use If else or `Switch` statement and my code is already working but My teacher said that my code is not correct because I use `private static String numberToWord(int number)` and `String unitsArray[]` he said that I may use only the things that we discuss in our class so I need to reconstruct my code.
Please help me to reconstruct my code. I'm so confused right now I can't think properly.

This is my code in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please type a number(max upto 9 digits)");

        // read the number
        number = scanner.nextInt();
        if (number == 0) {
            System.out.print("Number in words: Zero");
        } else {
            System.out.print(numberToWord(number));
        }

}
private static String numberToWord(int number) {
            // variable to hold string representation of number 
            String words = "";
    String unitsArray[] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", 
                            "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve",
                            "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", 
                            "eighteen", "nineteen" };
    String tensArray[] = { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty",
                             "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

    if (number == 0) {
        return "zero";
    }
    // add minus before conversion if the number is less than 0
    if (number < 0) { 
                    // convert the number to a string
                    String numberStr = "" + number;
                    // remove minus before the number 
                    numberStr = numberStr.substring(1);
                    // add minus before the number and convert the rest of number
                    return "minus " + numberToWord(Integer.parseInt(numberStr));
            } 
            // check if number is divisible by 1 million
            if ((number / 1000000) > 0) {
        words += numberToWord(number / 1000000) + " million ";
        number %= 1000000;
    }
    // check if number is divisible by 1 thousand
    if ((number / 1000) > 0) {
        words += numberToWord(number / 1000) + " thousand ";
        number %= 1000;
    }
    // check if number is divisible by 1 hundred
    if ((number / 100) > 0) {
        words += numberToWord(number / 100) + " hundred ";
        number %= 100;
    }
    if (number > 0) {
        // check if number is within teens
        if (number < 20) {
                             // fetch the appropriate value from unit array
                             words += unitsArray[number];
                    } else { 
                            // fetch the appropriate value from tens array
                            words += tensArray[number / 10]; 
                            if ((number % 10) > 0) {
               words += "-" + unitsArray[number % 10];
                        }  
        }
    }
    return words;
}
}
```

Comment: If the methods cannot be static then have to be instance methods. You need to create an instance of your class, and then call the method on it.

Comment: We do not know what you did not discuss in your class. Methods? static methods? Recusivity? Arrays?

Comment: So what did your teacher want you to use? did he give any indication? what was discussed in your class?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to check how the switch statement works and do not use the function, but put everything in the main function.
I'll give you a hint:

```
switch(number){
   case 1: "one"; 
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good, that this code works fine, but I can see some problems in it:

1. **String concatenation**

You use recursion (i.e. loops). Therefore each time when you type `str = str1 + str2` you have *three* strings in the JVM. You should use *StringBuilder* instead and at the end, convert it to the final string.

2. **Multiple array initializations**

In `numberToWord` method, you declare two arrays: `unitsArray[]` and `tensArray[]`. Every time, when you call this method, these array are been initialized again. If you use `static` method, just use *static initialization block* to declare these arrays only once and reuse it.

3. **Close external resources**

`Scanner scanner` scanner should be closed (it contains `close()` method). It is *not critical* for the scanner, but anyway, this is **must have**: when you use resource, do release it before quit.

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // payload
}
```

4. **You forget about *and* before last two digits.**

*1031* is *one thousand **and** thirty one*

5. **Do check corner cases within your code (make it simple to use for the clients).**

Your client code looks like:

```
number = scanner.nextInt();

if (number == 0)
    System.out.print("Number in words: Zero");
else
    System.out.print(numberToWord(number));
```

This is very bad practice. This check should be incapsulated in your logic. Client should not worry about corner cases: `System.out.print(numberToWord(scanner.nextInt()))`.

6. **OOP**

Actually, I do not mind to use `static` in some cases. But in the given example, your teacher is right: you have a task `convert number to the string representation` and this task contains some logic and internal constants. It is better to incapsulate it into separate class. It could be `static` class with only one public method `String convert(long val)` (but this is old-style and not OOP). You could create separate class, move your static method into it and remove `static`. This is enough (plus I would initialize array once, in the constructor). In general this is enough.

***P.S.***
Could I give you my solution to this problem. I split this task into two steps: first - convert the string into list of simple numbers (like *one, ten, hundred, million*) and then using predefined dictionary, convert these simple numbers into final string.

**E.g.**

*value*: `1001`

*numbers*: `[1, 1000, 1]`

*results*: `one thousand and one`

**My solution:**

```
public final class NumberToWordConverter {

    private final Long AND = null;
    private final Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    {
        map.put(AND, "and");
        map.put(0L, "zero");
        map.put(1L, "one");
        map.put(2L, "two");
        map.put(3L, "three");
        map.put(4L, "four");
        map.put(5L, "five");
        map.put(6L, "six");
        map.put(7L, "seven");
        map.put(8L, "eight");
        map.put(9L, "nine");
        map.put(10L, "ten");
        map.put(11L, "eleven");
        map.put(12L, "twelve");
        map.put(13L, "thirteen");
        map.put(14L, "fourteen");
        map.put(15L, "fifteen");
        map.put(16L, "sixteen");
        map.put(17L, "seventeen");
        map.put(18L, "eighteen");
        map.put(19L, "nineteen");
        map.put(20L, "twenty");
        map.put(30L, "thirty");
        map.put(40L, "forty");
        map.put(50L, "fifty");
        map.put(60L, "sixty");
        map.put(70L, "seventy");
        map.put(80L, "eighty");
        map.put(90L, "ninety");
        map.put(100L, "hundred");
        map.put(1000L, "thousand");
        map.put(1000000L, "million");
        map.put(1000000000L, "billion");
    }

    public String numberToWords(long val) {
        String str = parts(Math.abs(val), 1, new LinkedList<>()).stream()
                                                                .map(map::get)
                                                                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        return val < 0 ? "minus " + str : str;
    }

    private Deque<Long> parts(long val, long mul, Deque<Long> queue) {
        if (val >= 1000) {
            parts(val / 1000, mul * 1000, queue);

            if (val % 1000 > 0)
                parts(val % 1000, mul, queue);
        } else if (val <= 20) {
            if (mul == 1)
                queue.add(AND);

            queue.add(val);

            if (mul > 1)
                queue.add(mul);
        } else if (val < 100) {
            if (mul == 1)
                queue.add(AND);

            queue.add(val / 10 * 10);

            if (val % 10 > 0) {
                queue.add(val % 10);

                if (mul > 1)
                    queue.add(mul);
            }
        } else {
            queue.add(val / 100);
            queue.add(100L);

            if (val % 100 > 0)
                parts(val % 100, 1, queue);

            if (mul > 1)
                queue.add(mul);
        }

        return queue;
    }
}
```